# Spring Security: Keep only one active token per client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

We have a REST API secured with OAuth 2 client_credentials.
Right now every time we authenticate using client-id and client-credentials a new token is generated and the old one stays valid (as long as it has not expired).
Is there a way to invalidate the old token? We would like to keep a single token per client-id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OAuth token is a stateless mechanism in essence , OAuth is usually used when there is distinction between authorization server and resource server whereas also possible one party to handle both role same time.

if you want to set such a constraint you have to maintain the usage of tokens by clients and when generating a new token persist new one somewhere e.g a database table like a white list and when a client wants to access a resource his token not only should be valid also should be matched by the one that you maintaining as a valid one

Comment: I meant a single active token per client-id and not client.